# How can I write multiple filter in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am confusing how can I write the filter code in my serializers.py.
I have the following models.

```
User (AbstractBaseUser)
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128)


Clinic (models.Model)
    clinic_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, primary_key=True)
    clinic_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


Consultation (models.Model)
    consultation_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    clinic_id = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


Chat (models.Model)
    chat_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    consultation_id = models.ForeignKey(Consultation)
    DIDRESPONSE_CHOICE = {
        ('R', 'No'),
        ('C', 'Doing'),
        ('F', 'Done'),
    }
    did_response = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DIDRESPONSE_CHOICE, default='N')


ChatDetail (models.Model)
    chat_no = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    chat_id = models.ForeignKey(Chat)
    CHATFROM_CHOICE = {
        ('D', 'Doctor'),
        ('U', 'User'),
    }
    chat_from = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    chat = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)
```

I want to serialize above data and response to client in JSON format.

```
{
    'username': 'Tom Smith',
    'clinic_name': 'Adam's clinic',
    'consultation_id': 12345678, 
    'chat_id': 09876543, 
    'chat_detail' : [ 
        {'chat_no': 11122233, 'chat_from': 'D', 'chat': 'How are you doing today?'}, 
        {'chat_no': 11112234, 'chat_from': 'U', 'chat': 'I have a headache'},
        {'chat_no': 11122235, 'chat_from': 'D', 'chat': 'Oh, I'm sorry'},
        {'chat_no': 11122236, 'chat_from': 'U', 'chat': 'Can you help me?'},
    ] 
}
```

I made filters in my views.py by using override get_queryset method. But it wasn't not work. So, I tried to write filters in my serializers.py. But it is also didn't work(I don't understand how can I write above requirement filter in my serializers.py).

What should I do to achieve my requirement? Please help me please.

views.py

```
class WebViewChatDataOutputView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        chat_detail = ChatDetail
        serializer = WebViewChatDataOutputSerializer(chat_detail, many=True)
        filter_fields = ('chat_id')
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        consultation_id = self.request.consultation_id
        chat = Chat.objects.filter(consultation_id=consultation_id)
        return ChatDetail.objects.filter(chat_id=chat.chat_id)
```

serializers.py

```
class WebViewChatDataOutputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # class Meta:
    #     model = Consultation
    #     fields = ('consultation_id')
    #
    # class Meta:
    #     model = Chat
    #     fields = ('chat_id')
    #
    class Meta:
        chat = ChatDataForChatDetailSerializer(many=True)
        model = ChatDetail
        fields = ('chat_no', 'chat_from', 'chat')
```

I am trying to make a filter. But I got 'Meta.fields'; contains fields that are not defined on this FilterSet: ChatDetail, Chat" error.

My view is the following.

```
from .filtering import CategoryFilter

class WebViewChatDataOutputView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        filter_backends = (
            rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter,
            rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend
        )

        filter_class = CategoryFilter

        serializer = WebViewChatDataInputSerializer(chat_detail, many=True)
        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

And my filtering.py is the following.

```
class CategoryFilter(rest_framework.filters.FilterSet):

    name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name=ChatDetail,
        lookup_expr='chat_id'
    )
    parent_category_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name=Chat,
        lookup_expr='chat_id'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ChatDetail
        fields = ['ChatDetail', 'Chat']
```

Did I mistake any kind of grammar? Please gime an advice.

I updated my code.

views.py

```
class WebViewChatDataOutputView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):

        lookup_field = 'chat_id'
        queryset = Chat.objects.all()
        serializer_class = ChatSerializer

        return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class ChatDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatDetail
        fields = '__all__'


class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    username = serializers.CharField(source='consultation_id.user.username')  # You should rename the consultation_id foreign key field to consultation, by the way
    clinic_name = serializers.CharField(source='consultation_id.clinic_id.clinic_name')  # Same goes for clinic_id
    chat_detail = ChatDetailSerializer(many=True, source='chatdetail_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ('user_name', 'clinic_name', 'consultation_id', 'chat_id', 'chat_detail')
```

Comment: Can u show us your view code?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I added views.py and serializers.py. Would you help me please?

Comment: u solved your problem?

Comment: @Thaian Thank you for your kindness advice. But I can't understand how to write the program. So I did old style coding such as SQL because I had to write the code until 9/9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I put below couple solution to achieve filters for your endpoint.*

You can use **filter_class** but to do it use **ListApiView**. Create *filtering.py* and add there something(for quick example):

```
import django_filters
import rest_framework.filters

from categories import models as categories_models


class CategoryFilter(rest_framework.filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name='name',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )
    parent_category_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        name='parent_category__name',
        lookup_expr='icontains'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = categories_models.Category
fields = ['name', 'parent_category_name']
```

**In your view add:**

```
import rest_framework.filters

filter_backends = (
        rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter,
        rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend
    )

filter_class = categories_filtering.CategoryFilter
```

[More details you find in ListApiView inspector](http://www.cdrf.co/3.6/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html)

Its clear because you have another file only with filter logic and its seperated from your serializer.

**You can use also **get_queryset** but first u need add statment to check url for example:**

1. url contain q parametr with filter field
2. in method u need get q value and to something with these
3. write query to do it

but better idea is to use(u need change to Generic):
[Filter_queryset](http://www.cdrf.co/3.6/rest_framework.generics/GenericAPIView.html#filter_queryset)

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I made my code to use filter. But something is wrong. I got the error. I added my modified code. Would you give me an advice please?

Comment: @KazzzStudio put name in apostrofs `name='ChatDetail'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem is not filtering, in the DRF sense or the QuerySet sense, you simply need the right serializers and views for your models.

The output you shared refers to a given `Chat`. For the serializers, you'll need a `ChatSerializer` and a `ChatDetailSerializer` (for the list of `ChatDetail`s).

Your can use the `source` argument in your serializer fields to retrieve data from your related models, so `ChatSerializer` could look something like:

```
class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    username = serializers.CharField(source='consultation_id.user.username')  # You should rename the consultation_id foreign key field to consultation, by the way
    clinic_name = serializers.CharField(source='consultation_id.clinic_id.clinic_name')  # Same goes for clinic_id
    chat_detail = ChatDetailSerializer(many=True, source='chatdetail_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Chat
        fields = ('user_name', 'clinic_name', 'consultation_id', 'chat_id', 'chat_detail')
```

The `ChatDetailSerializer` can be a simple `ModelSerializer`

```
class ChatDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ChatDetail 
        fields = '__all__'
```

In your views, DRF needs to know how to fetch the data. You can use `get_queryset` for that, but that does nothing if you implement in on an `ApiView`, use a `RetrieveView` instead, since you're showing one model instance (a `ChatDetail`). Or use some other generic view depending on your needs (see the DRF documentation on the subject, http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview).

```
class WebViewChatDataOutputView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'chat_id'
    queryset = Chat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChatSerializer
```

And that's it. I hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I can understand this advice. I modify my code following to your advice. But I got <property object at 0x7f6fc363d138> is not JSON serializable. I tried to write seliarizer_class.serialize, but it was syntax error. How can I serialize the data from ChatSerializer?

Comment: @KazzzStudio This sounds like you're passing a model class to the serializer instead of a model instance. Did you update your view code? Your original view code would probably produce this error.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I updated my views.py "queryset = Chat.objects.all()". I believe this code setup instance instead of model class. I have no idea where is wrong.

Comment: I noticed to have to update models.py to consultation and clinic from consultation_id and clinic_id. So I did, I still got the error.

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `ChatSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'consultation_id'.

What is lack of my code? Please give me an advice.

Comment: If you are using the generic views, you should not override the get method. Look at the example in my answer, `serializer_class`, `lookup_filed` and `queryset` are class-level attributes, not local variables. If you want to define your own `get` method instead, you should pass a model instance, not a QuerySet or a model class to the serializer.